# add images to cache in service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

A page I want to take offline loads images dynamically. I managed to obtain a list of all [images on a page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp). but, I can't figure out a way to pass this list to the SW. before it loads cache.

I'm newbie in Web development sorry, If this question is childish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used global variable in the .js file where I registered the SW. I pushed all the image's addresses to this array using [`document.images`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp)and then used `window.arr` (arr is array) in SW.js to access them.

I knew it!. This is just a childish question but, I want to keep it because may be a newbie in asp.net and SW find it helpful. Let me know if it's not the case.